# String nil inside NSURLSession

Tags: swift

I declare a string in the beginning

```
var testString: String?


let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

    let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

    testString =  xml["root"]["schedule"]["date"].element?.text

}
```

But outside the NSURLSession, `testString` is nil. How can I make it so that it does not become nil and I can actually use the value?

For example, I want to use

```
println (testString)
```

AFTER the method block. But it is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your variable is nil is because closures are executed asynchronously. That means that the rest of the code after the network request will continue to be called as normal, but the code containing parameters data, response and error is only called when the network request is finished.

To work around this, try putting whatever you are trying to do with the variable inside the closure, so your `println(testString)` would be inside the curly brackets.

Comment: Awesome! That answers my question. However, actually what I want to do is set a label equal to what is in testString. I tried doing this inside the closure, but nothing appears in my label. Any idea for this?

Comment: Remember, UI updates must occur on the main thread:     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in  self?.label.text = testString }

Comment: @XamarinWarrior Make sure to put this code after your networking request -- it just starts it. Code: `task.resume()`